# How to get a string from c# code to XAML (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to get a string from my C# code over to my XAML, but I can't seem to find a way to do it

My C# code

```
public string demoColour= "#FFFFFF";
```

My XAML Code

```
...
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{ NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE :( }"/>
</Trigger>                            
...
```

Comment: Take a look at data binding. Or make demoColour a static class member and use `x:Static`.

Comment: I seem to understand how to do it now, this article here helped: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm
Thanks for telling me what to look into

Comment: [What is Databinding?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview)

Answer (score 2):

As Clemes said, you should take a look at data binding. 
Data binding is one really important thing in WPF.

But here is one Solution, which works fine:

1. Make a new Class called ViewModel
2. Add a Property to that Class like `public string MyColor { get; set; } = "#FFFFFF";`
3. Set the DataContext in your XAML:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

4. Bind your Property to your XAML whereever you want. For Example:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyColor}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```